# Unable to find robots.txt file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, robots.txt

In a Vue (3.4) app, I have created a robots.txt file at the root of my folder. I have deployed my website with the robots.txt file and I am unable to find it when typing the URL https://www.example.com/robots.txt/ I get a 404.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `https://www.example.com/robots.txt` instead of `https://www.example.com/robots.txt/` without the trailing slash. Or was that just a typo in the question?

Comment: Aren't all public pages supposed to go in the "public" folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put it in your public folder. Only stuff in that folder is directly accessible from the web. Hence why css/js files are in there

Answer (score 2):

Put the robots file in `public` folder. You should put any files that you want to access in the build output (production). [Read](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)